# Python with virtual evironment not working with my own package

Tags: python, pyvenv

My project looks like this:

```
src
 |--annotation_correction
 |--|--suggestion.py
 |--|--error.py
 |--|--...
venv
 |--...
```

I installed my package, using `pip install -e .` while in the main folder.
When I type `pip freeze`, my package "annotation" is in the list and VSCode also seems to recognize it as an installed package.

The problem is that when I run `suggestion.py` while trying to import e.g. from error.py with `from annotation_correction.error import Error, ErrorType`, I still get the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'annotation_correction.error'; 'annotation_correction' is not a package`

All this while using the interpreter that is running in the venv.

My `setup.py` just calls `setup()` and my `setup.cfg` looks like this:

```
...
packages = 
    annotation_correction
...
package_dir =
    =src
```

Comment: Please show a mcve of shell commands that show the venv and install

Comment: You need to run the install from the `src` folder

Comment: @MadPhysicist what exactly do you want to see from the venv? Install looked like this: `Collecting [package]` for all required packages and in the end: `Running setup.py develop for annotation-correction
Successfully installed annotation-correction [other packages]`

Comment: Good point. I really just needed to know the folder you ran install in, and the output

Comment: In the `setup.cfg` I specified the package directory to be the src folder.

Comment: Where is the link in site packages pointing to?

Comment: To the src folder.

Comment: I don't see a `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` in your example

Comment: Please add the setup files

Comment: You are right, I'm gonna update the post, give me a second.

Comment: Thanks for staying responsive

Comment: `=src` appears to be a typo in your configuration

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, that's not a typo. [That specifies the src layout.](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#using-a-src-layout) Also, install does _not_ need to be run from the src folder.

Comment: Anyway: how do you "run suggestion.py"? You need to use the `-m` flag (e.g. `python -m annotation_correction.suggestion`) to have paths set up correctly.

Comment: Yeah I just tested it, it doesn't work with out the `=`. I run the .py via F5 and then using the interpreter that uses venv. Running it from the console yielded the same results.

Comment: @AKX wow, this was acutally the solution. Using `-m` in the console works. Do you know a way to make VSCode use it? Otherwise I'm gonna look for it now. Thanks a lot to you two!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my comment an answer:

If you have a module in a package that imports other modules from the same package with `from package import module` or `from . import module` or similar, then you will need to use [the `-m` switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

> Search `sys.path` for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module.

Otherwise, Python will have set up `sys.path` so the directory of the script that is run is in it, which will naturally wreak havoc with imports (since the package is "invisible").

This stands whether or not you've installed a package (and indeed you don't necessarily need to `pip install -e` the same package you're working on) or not.

The other option is to have a standalone script outside the package that acts as the entry point and does e.g. `from annotation_correction.suggestion import main` (since from that script's point of view, the package is there and all is fine -- and if the package is installed, `-e` or no `-e`, the script doesn't even need to be next to the package directory, since the package has been installed and as such on the search path), but that's unnecessary.

Visual Studio Code apparently [supports the same thing with a "module" run configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_module).