Pytest can't find imports from tested modules
I am trying to test a package with the following structure:
.
├── src\
├──--myproject\
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   ├── module2.py
│   └── main.py
├──-tests\
    ├──test_simple.py
    ├──test_module1.py

I am running with a virtualenv.
#test_simple.py

def test_tests_working() -> None:
    assert 1 == 1

#test_module1.py

import sys
sys.path.append(r"path_to_project\src") #i got this from another SO answer but didn't seem to resolve anything
from myproject.module1 import func1

def test_func1() -> None:
    blah = func1(args)
    assert blah == "expected func1 results"

test_simple works fine, returns True, so I know pytest itself is working okay and its looking in the right places so and so forth, sanity checks check out. However, when I get to test_module1, I get an error on line 1 because in module1 it's trying to import another module, which causes failure:
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'

#module1.py

import module2

def func1():
   #do stuff

Why is it not working? If I run the scripts directly, or even from another script, I have no issues with the import statements being the way they are. I tried to change to from . import module2 but that didn't solve it. I deleted the tests/__init__.py file on a another SO recommendation as well, but to no avail.

You have a package myproject; see my (old) answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57884086/51685 https://stackoverflow.com/a/71196134/51685
